# How to tell tasks and other code blocks apart in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have a build.gradle file cobbled together from examples online:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceSets {
    java {
        srcDirs = ['src']
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        name "fileRepo"
        dirs "repo"
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        add project.repositories.fileRepo
    }
}
```

When I run `gradle tasks --all`, I can see that "uploadArchives" is a task. How can I tell what is a task by looking at the build.gradle file? If "repositories" and "sourceSets" aren't considered tasks, what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You simply can't.**

But, the pure knowledge whether a closure configures a task or something else, won't give you anything. To understand a build script, you will need to understand the basic concept of Gradle and the used plugins, either built-in or third-party.

Each `build.gradle` script is executed against a [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) instance. Everything you can access from the build script belongs to one of the following scopes:

> - The `Project` object itself. This scope includes any property getters and setters declared by the Project implementation class. For example, `getRootProject()` is accessible as the `rootProject` property. The properties of this scope are readable or writable depending on the presence of the corresponding getter or setter method.
> - The extra properties of the project. Each project maintains a map of extra properties, which can contain any arbitrary name -> value pair. Once defined, the properties of this scope are readable and writable. See [extra properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#extraproperties) for more details.
> - The extensions added to the project by the plugins. Each extension is available as a read-only property with the same name as the extension.
> - The convention properties added to the project by the plugins. A plugin can add properties and methods to a project through the project's `Convention` object. The properties of this scope may be readable or writable, depending on the convention objects.
> - The tasks of the project. A task is accessible by using its name as a property name. The properties of this scope are read-only. For example, a task called compile is accessible as the `compile` property.
> - The extra properties and convention properties are inherited from the project's parent, recursively up to the root project. The properties of this scope are read-only.

For your specific example, `uploadArchives` is a task, `repositories` belongs to the original `Project` object (it is available in each build script) and `sourceSets` is an extension of the `java` plugin.

Please note, that many plugins do not require or plan direct task configuration. They provide a DSL extension for configuration and then generate the tasks based on this configuration.